# SQL Server FTS: Ranking is a bit strange

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am using SQL Server 2008's Full Text Search engine in my website. I have a search SP, which shows results sorted based on ranking.

I break up the search string and pass it to the FTS query engine like so (search string is 'test search':

```
("*test*" ~ "*search*") OR ("*test*" OR "*search*").
```

If the results row has the row 'test search', and other has 'test something else'. The latter is being ranked higher.

I don't understand how this could be - obviously the phrase 'test search' is a closer match. I figure it has something to do with the way I'm passing the test string to FTS.  Any insights? Suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the SP and Table schema on which the search is done.

Answer (score 2):

All search terms that are OR'ed have equal weight.  In order to increase the rank of the phrase "test NEAR search", you must specify a greater weight.

Example

```
SELECT 
  Srch.*
FROM 
  CONTAINSTABLE
  (
    MyTable, 
    SearchColumn, 
    -- must specify a weight if one phrase is more important
    'ISABOUT(test ~ search weight(.7), test weight(.1), search weight(.2))', 
    LANGUAGE 1033, -- english
    100            -- TOP N RANK
  ) Srch
```